# How to Hide Console Window for GUI apps on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, console

On Windows 11 there are several GUI programs (for example, the [jzIntv](https://www.intellivision.us/intvgames/jzintv/jzintv.php) emulator) that I use which open a console window in the background, in addition to the main GUI window. Is there some method or utility I can use that will enable running and showing the GUI, but hiding the console window?

I have tried using [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (exec and/or execmd commands) with limited success. I find for some programs this works (e.g. execmd works for [Mame](https://www.mamedev.org/)), but for most apps (e.g. jzIntv) it will hide both the GUI and the console windows, which is not what I want.

[image: Example screenshot of both windows]

Comment: Why did you delete your original question instead of editing your question allowing it to be reopened.

Comment: @Ramhound I did exactly that and it did not get re-opened.  I did not know if it ever would.  The comment on the blocking messages said "You can edit the question or post a new one" ... if you don't think this was good advice then you should take it up with the site host.

Comment: When it says "ask a new question" it actually means asking an entirely different question not submitting the same question. You likely didn't give the community enough time to reopen it.

Comment: @Ramhound, maybe that's what was meant, maybe not, but it's definitely not what was said.  The entrenched communities on these sites are very quick to condemn and slow to praise, I waited 3 times as long as it took to close my question before giving up and posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a .bat file to run the app.
2. Make a *shortcut* to the .bat file.
3. Open the shortcut the *Properties*.
4. Set *Run* to `Minimized`.

Now, when you click the shortcut, or call it through the the keyboard, the CMD prompt will be hidden, but the app it's running should show normally.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I have no doubt this is a good solution for many, but I am looking for something that will work when called from another program or batch file, and I don't think you can do that with shortcuts.

Comment: Yes, you *can* call a shortcut from another application. For example, in *Clavier+*, I use "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\SIFirefox.bat.lnk" to call the link directly, not it's destination. Note use of **.lnk** at end.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm at least 99% certain this didn't work for me yesterday (the GUI window never appeared), today this approach is working for me, maybe a reboot was all I needed to sort out this approach using [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html):

```
nircmd execmd ./path/to/program.exe <param1> <param2>
```

The console now remains hidden while the GUI window appears as desired.